Astro swetest program output in array works locally on server while on browser it empty array
Below code works fine locally on Alma linux 8 version run on cpanel while on browser the array gives empty value. Please advice. Both Apache user & user who is executing the below code is same.
However on browser.. it gives below response.... i.e. Empty array Array ( ) I am expecting the full results in array. We are using sweph swetest program for horoscope.
<?Php 
exec("swetest -b$20.06.1998 -ut02.40.00 -p0123456789DAttt -eswe -house40,37,p -flsj -g -head", $ram); 
print_r($ram);
?>


$ php tt.php

exec works
Array ( \[0\] =\> 69.4699711 0.9589330 12.7711722 \[1\] =\> 137.2047430 12.6210423 3.6491743 \[2\] =\> 57.5155629 2.0043804 12.4929126 \[3\] =\> 31.3153898 1.1640522 11.8892585 \[4\] =\> 64.9341541 0.7061970 12.6475111 \[5\] =\> 354.5698247 0.1370835 10.9268075 \[6\] =\> 29.0617305 0.1066860 11.8413060 \[7\] =\> 312.6691481 -0.0108831 9.4849388 \[8\] =\> 301.9767792 -0.0136113 9.0252288 \[9\] =\> 246.6157497 -0.0273073 7.0543078 \[10\] =\> 223.8406492 -0.0627669 6.1963588 \[11\] =\> 198.5784533 0.1113581 5.6143622 \[12\] =\> 155.4844488 -0.0261982 4.3224287 \[13\] =\> 155.4844488 -0.0261982 4.3224287 \[14\] =\> 155.4844488 -0.0261982 4.3224287 \[15\] =\> 78.0000935 4.3224287 \[16\] =\> 99.9959839 4.3224287 \[17\] =\> 121.4227768 4.3224287 \[18\] =\> 146.1570660 4.3224287 \[19\] =\> 178.0430227 4.3224287 \[20\] =\> 218.1001694 4.3224287 \[21\] =\> 258.0000935 4.3224287 \[22\] =\> 279.9959839 4.3224287 \[23\] =\> 301.4227768 4.3224287 \[24\] =\> 326.1570660 4.3224287 \[25\] =\> 358.0430227 4.3224287 \[26\] =\> 38.1001694 4.3224287 \[27\] =\> 78.0000935 4.3224287 \[28\] =\> 326.1570660 4.3224287 \[29\] =\> 328.3998653 4.3224287 \[30\] =\> 220.1804870 4.3224287 ) 

Browser should display values of array
